# Greasemonkey script to replace all URLs on a page with a certain domain to a different one

Tags: javascript, regex, greasemonkey

I want to replace all links on the site https://www.reddit.com/r/videos/ that have the `youtube.com` or `youtu.be` domain with a different domain

I created this script that successfully replaces all `youtube.com` with `youpak.com`, but the `youtu.be` links aren't replaced for some reason

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        replace r/videos youtube with youpak
// @namespace   test
// @include     https://www.reddit.com/r/videos/
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var regexFull = /^https:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/(.*)$/i;
var regexShort = /^https:\/\/\.youtu\.be\/(.*)$/i;
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].href = links[i].href.replace(regexFull, 'https://www.youpak.com/$1');
  links[i].href = links[i].href.replace(regexShort, 'https://www.youpak.com/watch/?v=$1');
}
```

---

An example URL for the `regexFull` rule would be  `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L4iyPXHM89E`

I want this URL to be changed to `https://www.youpak.com/watch?v=L4iyPXHM89E`

**This works**

---

An example URL for the `regexShort` rule would be `https://youtu.be/MkPU6P9OJv4` and `https://youtu.be/MkPU6P9OJv4?t=10`

I want this URL to be changed to `https://www.youpak.com/watch?v=MkPU6P9OJv4` and `https://www.youpak.com/watch?v=MkPU6P9OJv4?t=10` respectively

**This doesn't work**

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the escaping the regexShort URL looks like

```
^https://.youtu.be/(.*)$
```

As you can see there is an extra dot before 'youtu' that should not be there.

Try:

```
var regexShort = /^https:\/\/youtu\.be\/(.*)$/i;
```